# CDN Fallback 404 so slow that local script does not load fast enough

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, requirejs, modernizr

I am using a CDN to load JQuery and JQuery Mobile.  Between them I have to load a mobileinit script which seems to indicate that the jqm script will be partially downloaded when it starts to fire to config the global settings for it.

http://api.jquerymobile.com/mobileinit/

So in my page I have first:

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='~/Scripts/mobile/jquery-1.10.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
  }
</script>
```

then 2nd it does this:

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (typeof jQuery.mobile == 'undefined') {
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='~/Scripts/mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
  }
</script>
```

Even after all these scripts are loaded at the top I then have local scripts which execute after this.  2 errors continue to popup.

'Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined'
'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined'

I am wonder if the script block which uses document.write to add the local reference to the script is actually loading the script.  I was considering perhaps using something like Modernizr.Load to ensure the script is actually loaded to then proceed to load the rest, but there appeared to be issues with this as well.  I google this issue and time and time again, people on the internet seem to say that document.write is the way to do this.